# How to convert R formula to text?

Tags: r, r-formula

I have trouble working with formula as with text. What I'm trying to do is to concatenate the formula to the title of the graph. However, when I try to work with the formula as with text, I fail:

```
model <- lm(celkem ~ rok + mesic)
formula(model)
# celkem ~ rok + mesic
```

This is fine. Now I want to build string like `"my text celkem ~ rok + mesic"` - this is where the problem comes:

```
paste("my text", formula(model))
# [1] "my text ~"           "my text celkem"      "my text rok + mesic"

paste("my text", as.character(formula(model)))
# [1] "my text ~"           "my text celkem"      "my text rok + mesic"

paste("my text", toString(formula(model)))
# [1] "my text ~, celkem, rok + mesic"
```

Now I see there is a `sprint` function in package `gtools`, but I think this is such a basic thing that it deserves a solution within the default environment!!

Comment: `sprint` is not part of `gtools` any more. Anyone know what is the solution to this post?

Comment: Anybody know why this list gymnastics is the default behaviour of `formula(model)`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Simplest solution covering everything:

```
f <- formula(model)
paste(deparse(f, width.cutoff = 500), collapse="")
```

Comment: R 4.0.0 (released 2020-04-24) introduced deparse1 which never splits the result into multiple strings (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62930525/1870254))

Answer (score 51):

A short solution from the package `formula.tools`, as a function `as.character.formula`:

```
frm <- celkem ~ rok + mesic
Reduce(paste, deparse(frm))
# [1] "celkem ~ rok + mesic"

library(formula.tools)
as.character(frm)
# [1] "celkem ~ rok + mesic"
```

`Reduce` might be useful in case of long formulas:

```
frm <- formula(paste("y ~ ", paste0("x", 1:12, collapse = " + ")))

deparse(frm)
# [1] "y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 + x10 + x11 + "
# [2] "    x12"                                                      
Reduce(paste, deparse(frm))
# [1] "y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 + x10 + x11 +      x12"
```

Which is because of `width.cutoff = 60L` in `?deparse`.

Comment: Aaah, `deparse`! Thanks a million! However, why you use `Reduce`? It is enough to do just `deparse(frm)`.

Comment: @Tomas, just added an explanation about `Reduce`.

Comment: Erghh, I was so enthusiastic about deparse, but now it seems it is quite deceitful! There must be some function that converts formula to string *without wrappings, cutoffs* etc!!

Comment: @Tomas, I don't think there is one which would be significantly shorter than your solution. I think `deparse` alone is sufficient for visual usage and `Reduce` + `deparse` is not that bad in long formulas for non visual usage.

Comment: it is not ideal, I need visual usage and deparse alone will not do the job. There must be something that that generates simple string from the formula!

Comment: BTW, `Reduce(paste, deparse(frm))` is a nice trick to replace `paste(deparse(frm), collapse=' ')`, thanks.

Comment: @TMS`Reduce(paste, deparse(frm, width.cutoff = 500))` seems to do the trick.

Comment: No more `Reduce(paste, deparse(.))` or `paste(deparse(.), collapse=' ')`: R 4.0.0 (released 2020-04-24) introduced deparse1 which never splits the result into multiple strings (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62930525/1870254))

Answer (score 36):

Try `format` :

```
paste("my text", format(frm))
## [1] "my text celkem ~ rok + mesic"
```

Comment: thanks, however this has the same problem with wrapping long formulas as `deparse` has, disregarding the width and justify options...

Comment: It worked when I tried your example but, yes, I have checked the source now and it does indeed call `deparse`.  It seems that `deparse(fo, cutoff.width = 200)` works but there is no way to pass that argument to deparse when using `format`.

Answer (score 17):

R 4.0.0 (released 2020-04-24) introduced [`deparse1`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/deparse.html) which never splits the result into multiple strings:

```r
f <- y ~ a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + 
     p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z
deparse(f)
# [1] "y ~ a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + " "    p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z"                   
deparse1(f)
# [1] "y ~ a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z"
```

---

---

---

However, it still has a `width.cutoff` argument (default (an maximum): `500`) after which linebreaks are introduced but with lines separated by `collapse` (default: `" "`) not `\n`, leaving extra white whitespace (even with `collapse = ""`) (use `gsub` to remove them if needed, see [Ross D's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31153246/1870254)):

```r
> f <- rlang::parse_expr( paste0("y~", paste0(rep(letters, 20), collapse="+")))
> deparse1(f, collapse = "")
[1] "y ~ a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z + a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z + a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z + a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z + a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u +     v + w + x + y + z + a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z + a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z + a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z + a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z + a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p +     q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z + a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z + a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z + a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z + a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z + a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k +     l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z + a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z + a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z + a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z + a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z + a + b + c + d + e + f +     g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v + w + x + y + z"
```

---

To use it in R < 4.0.0 use [`backports`](https://github.com/r-lib/backports) (recommended)
or copy it's implementation:

```
#  Part of the R package, https://www.R-project.org
#
#  Copyright (C) 1995-2019 The R Core Team
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  A copy of the GNU General Public License is available at
#  https://www.R-project.org/Licenses/

deparse1 <- function (expr, collapse = " ", width.cutoff = 500L, ...) 
    paste(deparse(expr, width.cutoff, ...), collapse = collapse)
```

Comment: Best answer. Easy and do not need additional libs.

Answer (score 12):

or as an alternative to Julius's version (note: your code was not self-contained)

```
celkem = 1
rok = 1
mesic = 1
model <- lm(celkem ~ rok + mesic)
paste("my model ", deparse(formula(model)))
```

Comment: .. but be careful, it poses the problem mentioned by Julius - deparse will cutoff long formulas.

Comment: Interesting ... never thought of that.

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way is this:

```
f = formula(model)
paste(f[2],f[3],sep='~')
```

done!

Comment: This is by far the best general-purpose answer. It is base R and does not have the `width.cutoff` issue like `deparse` and `format()`.

Answer (score 2):

Here a solution which use `print.formula`, it seems trick but it do the job in oneline and avoid the use of `deparse` and no need to use extra package. I just capture the output of the print formula, using `capture.output`

```
paste("my text",capture.output(print(formula(celkem ~ rok + mesic))))
[1] "my text celkem ~ rok + mesic"
```

In case of long formula:

```
 ff <- formula(paste("y ~ ", paste0("x", 1:12, collapse = " + ")))
 paste("my text",paste(capture.output(print(ff)), collapse= ' '))

 "my text y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 + x10 + x11 +      x12"
```

Comment: Thanks, but `capture.output(print())` can be just simplified to `deparse()` as Julius proposed, with exactly the same result: `paste(deparse(frm), collapse= ' ')`...

Answer (score 2):

Another `deparse`-based solution is `rlang::expr_text()` (and `rlang::quo_text()`):

```r
f <- Y ~ 1 + a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i +j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u
rlang::quo_text(f)
#> [1] "Y ~ 1 + a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + \n    o + p + q + r + s + t + u"
```

They do have a width argument to avoid line breaks, but that is limited to 500 characters too. At least it's a single function that is most likely loaded already...

Answer (score 1):

Then add gsub to remove white spaces

```
gsub("  ", "", paste(format(frm), collapse = ""))
```

Comment: Then? Isn't this keyword is preceded by an if?

Comment: My addition to @G. Grothendieck

Comment: This is more of a comment on another post than an answer in and of itself. Once you have enough rep, you can comment on any post. You can always comment on your own posts.

Answer (score 1):

Was optimizing some functions today. A few approaches that have not been mentioned so far.

```r
f <- Y ~ 1 + a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + n + o + p + q + r + s + t + u
bench::mark(
  expression = as.character(as.expression(f)),
  deparse = deparse(f, width.cutoff = 500L),
  deparse1 = deparse1(f),
  tools = formula.tools:::as.character.formula(f),
  stringi = stringi::stri_c(f),
  I = as.character(I(f)),
  as = as(f, "character"),
  txt = gettext(f),
  txtf = gettextf(f),
  sub = sub("", "", f),
  chr = as.character(f),
  str = substring(f, 1L),
  paste = paste0(f),
)[c(1, 3, 5, 7)]

#> # A tibble: 13 x 3
#>    expression   median mem_alloc
#>    <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:byt>
#>  1 expression   15.4us        0B
#>  2 deparse        31us        0B
#>  3 deparse1       34us        0B
#>  4 tools        58.7us    1.74MB
#>  5 stringi        67us    3.09KB
#>  6 I            64.1us        0B
#>  7 as          100.5us  521.61KB
#>  8 txt          83.4us        0B
#>  9 txtf         85.8us    3.12KB
#> 10 sub          64.6us        0B
#> 11 chr            60us        0B
#> 12 str          62.8us        0B
#> 13 paste        63.5us        0B
```

Comment: Speed and benchmarking isn't a concern at all. If you have an approach which is functionally better (in any other regard) than the other solutions here, please describe.

Comment: 1/6 th of the speed IS functionally better